# Cursor to selected not center?

Tags: mesh, selection-tools, snapping, 3d-cursor

I have several faces selected below. However when I CTRL + S and choose "cursor to selected", it doesn't snap to the exact center of the selected faces - it's just slightly off?

See below

[image]

Comment: Is your object really symmetrical? Also make sure that the object is not scaled in object mode (and apply scale if it has)

Comment: I seem to see lots of zero sized faces there, and overall duplicate geometry which could lead to all matter of unexpected behavior

Comment: Could you please give more detail regarding zero side faces and how to resolve them?